# While using train_and_evaluate() in tf.contrib.learn.Experiment, how to print result to the screen

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow high-level api `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` with `train_and_evaluate()` function. I want to print out evaluation result(model output) during evaluation period which is inside `train_and_evaluate()`

Answer (score 0):

Running train_and_evaluate() on a tf Experiment will print the evaluation metrics to stdout. From your description, it is likely that the evaluation is actually never run.

Make sure that checkpoints are saved at a higher frequency than the evaluation (min_eval_frequency). The evaluation step loads the model from the last checkpoint so a checkpoint file needs to be written out before the evaluation starts.

Furthermore, it might be that the loggin verbosity is prohibiting the output. Can the logging verborsity is set to INFO via:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

Comment: There was a missed description in my question. Actually, what I train is an seq2seq model and I want to output the decoder output when evaluating it. Furthermore, I want convert the decoder output to string with dictionary and print it out.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that so you hopefully get help soon on that question. Currently, you are asking about evaluation results, not direct outputs your model.